# Can you pass a digital certificate as a parameter, use it to sign, and not store it locally?

Tags: c#, visual-c++, digital-signature, digital-certificate

I've searched for this but have yet to find an answer.

If I want to sign something using a digital certificate, I usually have to have it in my certificate store.

But, is it possible to pass a digital certificate as a method parameter, use the cerficate to sign the document, and NOT store it locally in any way?

I would either do this in C++ or C#.

Comment: With CryptoAPI this is done by creating an in- memory store (not sure if .NET Framework allows this or you need to use P/Invoke). Or you can use a third-party library such as BouncyCastle or our SecureBlackbox to do the job (especially if you need some advanced signing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use various constructors of the [`X509Certificate2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms148409.aspx) Class to create a certificate from a file or byte array.  E.g.:

```
string certFile = @"MyCert.pfx";
string pfxPassword = "password"; // never hard code password in code

X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(certFile, pfxPassword, 
    X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);
RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaCsp = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)certificate.PrivateKey;
```

You can then use the crypto service provider for signing as in [How to: Sign XML Documents with Digital Signatures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229745.aspx).

Now does this "NOT store it locally in any way"?  Well, not entirely.  The certificate is **not** stored but the private keys **are** stored in the Microsoft Cryptographic API Cryptographic Service Provider key database.